# show data refreshed time in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel which has sql queries associated with it. I open the excel , click on Data->Refresh All and send across to the users.

When I click on refresh All , I want the refreshed date to appear in a cell on that sheet. Can you give some hint on this.

Comment: `Can you give some hint on this` google has plenty of hints XD

Comment: I have spent hours together searching for this but there is no complete answer for the scenario i am looking at

Comment: If you truly `spent hours` and have found **no** hints may I suggest you hire someone?

Comment: Instead of coming over here and commenting on my questions, if you were so genius you could have answered it. When you cant answer why do you comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the Ribbon to perform the Refresh, try a little macro like:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    With Range("A1")
        .Value = Now()
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    End With
End Sub
```

Pick whatever cell you like.

Comment: With macros it works but is there any way to do it without using macros ? Just click on refresh all in the ribbon and a cell gets the date when I clicked the ribbon.

Comment: @NaveenRam  You would still need a macro to record the time.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Upvote from me!

Answer (score 4):

Add another SQL Query somewhere else in your workbook 
SELECT GETDATE()
Make sure you refer to the same database your original query is referring to.
when you refresh the spread sheet the date will be updated as well.

1. Select Data ribbon
2. From Other Sources
3. From Microsoft Query
4. Choose DataBase (same as one used for the original Query)
5. "Query Wizard - Choose Columns" Click Cancel
6. "Do you want to continue editing the data in Query" Click Yes
7. "Add Tables" Click Close
8. Click on "SQL Button" and add the query there "SELECT GETDATE()"
9. Click OK
10. Click on Return data to Microsoft Excel

Comment: My problem is: Excel automatically formats the date using a date format I don't like. Changing the cell properties doesn't seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 1):

after searching various Excel related sites (mrexcel.com, exceltown.com and answers.microsoft.com) i've decided that the best solution (for me) does NOT need Macro or another query:

1. add as a last column in your existing query whatever function provides the current date and time [for Ingres it's **date('now')**]
2. hide the column from the resulting table
3. in the cell that you desire to show the last date & time that your table was refreshed enter the formula max(j:j). substitute j with the column that you've hidden.

simple :)

Comment: Funny that I looked for a solution today and you answered this yesterday.  
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This was the easiest way for me to get a refresh date. Add a =Date.Time.LocalNow() column. Hide Column. https://exceloffthegrid.com/power-query-get-refresh-date-time/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).